# Cannot access website running on port 8888 at AWS EC2 instance

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, security-groups

I am running an EC2 instance with AWS Linux. There is a website running there on port 8888, so if from the VM I run `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8888/login"` I receive the website.

I want to access it from outside, so I set up a rule in the security group attached to the instance:

```
Custom TCP Rule  TCP  8888  0.0.0.0/0
```

When I tried to access it from my browser or command line, I get a timeout

```
curl "http://xx.yy.zz.ff:8888/login"
```

Where `xx.yy.zz.ff` is the elastic IP attached to the instance (which I use to connect to the VM via SSH).

Interestingly, I can access it on `http://localhost:8888/login` if I do SSH tunnelling first:

```
ssh -i my-key.pem -NL 8888:localhost:8888 me@xx.yy.zz.ff
```

If I do sudo netstat -tulpn I get

```
tcp    0      0     127.0.0.1:8888   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      26531/python
```

And If I `do sudo ss -aut | grep 8888` I get nothing at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your webserver is only listening on `localhost`? Please edit your question and post the output of `$ ss -tuln | grep 8888`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tcp    0      0     127.0.0.1:8888   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      26531/python
```

Well, there's your answer. Your webserver (python process) is only listening on your localhost interface. So you'll either need to reconfigure that to listen on your EC2's external network interface *or* install nginx to use as a reverse proxy.